# Why do servers not accept email address comments?

Tags: email, email-server, mailbox, address

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part) Email addresses can contain comments in parentheses like `john.smith(comment)@example.com`.

I tried to send out some mails to valid Email addresses using such comments using several Email servers but all of them complained that the email address does not exist (`Unknown address
 error 550-'Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable' (delivery
 attempts: 0)>`).

Do Email servers not support comments usually and what is the reason for getting this error ?

Comment: What type of client you have used to generate this email and please add your email server type and related more details

Comment: This is like extended addressing, which needs to be configured server-side for which character separates address from comment area.  Note that the default is `+` but I've noticed issues when sending/receiving via Office365... so on my servers I've changed the character to `-`

Comment: @ChamindaBandara: I tried Evolution and the Outlook web interface.

Comment: @ivanivan: Are you sure it's an server-side extension? Comments are part of RFC 5322.

Comment: [RFC 5322 section 3.4.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.4.1) states that _Comments and folding white space SHOULD NOT be used around the "@" in the addr-spec._ However, there are 5 entries for this specific statement in the [RFC 5322 errata](http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=5322), suggesting the wording or intent is unclear to implementers. I would guess some MTA vendors treat it as "MAY NOT" and simply disallow it.

Comment: @JamesSneeringer, the thing is, that this is not only valid for john.smith(comment)@example.com but for john.smit(comment)h@example.com, too.

Comment: I may be thinking of the `recipient_delimiter` option (typically +, but outlook/outlook web doesn't handle it well so i configure it to be - on my servers).  On that note, Outlook web interface and office 365 both have given me issues with per-RFC addressing options.  Support may come down to the client being used as well as server side configuration/support

Answer (score 7):

I'm somewhat guessing, but maybe this still helps you:
There are two places where the recipient address is used. First is inside the e-mail as a header-field ("To:"), second is in the SMTP dialog when issueing the `RCPT` command. The latter is usually called the "envelope" recipient.

RFC5322 describes the Internet Message Format (i.e. the header and content of an e-mail message), but not the SMTP protocol.
In RFC5321 (which is the SMTP pendant to RFC5322) there is no mention of a comment in an e-mail address.

Thus, chances are that your servers are right, because your client should have removed the comment before using it as an envelope-address. If that had been done, your envelope-sender would be SMTP-friendly for the server to handle and the comment is still *inside* the e-mail (as a header) for the recipient.